# Can you use sleep dart on Junkrat's RIP-Tire?

Tags: overwatch

If I shoot Junkrat's tire with a sleep dart, does it stop moving? This might not make much sense at first, but you can put D.va's mech to sleep (she is able to move her joysticks still!), and you can also put Bastion and Zenyatta to sleep, so I wouldn't put it past Blizzard to make this possible as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. If you shoot a Junkrat's tire with a sleep dart, it does not put the tire to sleep, immobilize it, or slow it down.

It'll do 5 damage, and that's it.

Comment: source? How do you know?

Comment: Source: Me. I've played the game.